# Rails 3. Creating a production database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-schema

How can I create a production database in Rails 3 and load a schema to it?

I tried the following approaches...

I.

```
rake db:create Rails.env='production' && rake db:schema:load Rails.env='production'
```

II.

```
# config/environment.rb
# Set the rails environment
Rails.env='production'
rake db:create && rake db:schema:load
```

... but neither of them works.

Thanks.

Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.6;

Rails 3.0.0;

Sqlite3 3.7.2.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can set the rails env off of the environment variable `RAILS_ENV`

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load
```

should work

Comment: just watch out that you don't destroy an existing database.  if your schema  has force => true you could be in for a bad day

Answer (score 12):

Shouldn't this be

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load
```