# Correct Ruby on Rails 3 replacement for ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'production'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

We're doing an upgrade to Ruby on Rails 3 (like half the world right now), and I've been diligently replacing usages of RAILS_ENV, for example

```
RAILS_ENV == 'wibble'
# becomes
Rails.env.wibble?
```

But I'm not as certain of what to do with:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'production'
```

We've got it at the top of a whole bunch of [Rake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_%28software%29) tasks and daemons, and the idea is that you can pass `RAILS_ENV` on the command-line, but it defaults to 'production' if it's not passed.

I'm not sure of the new Rails3-appropriate way of doing this. So for now my `rails:upgrade:check` is complaining mightily of this intrusion of Rails2-ishness...

I don't know if:

```
::Rails.env ||= 'production'
```

will work.

Does `Rails.env` exist in a daemon?

Does it automagickally get pre-populated with the value of RAILS_ENV passed on the command-line or do we need a new way of invoking the daemons?

What is the correct mantra for this?

---

Update:

Looking into the source-code for `Rails.env`,

```
def env
  @_env ||= ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(RAILS_ENV)
end
```

we can deduce a number of things.

Firstly, it looks like `RAILS_ENV` does actually still exist - which means it can be set and `Rails.env` will find it...

If Rails is valid in the context of a daemon, then nothing more needs to be done. If not - then I could just not care much and use the old `RAILS_ENV` as before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Rails.env` is actually of type `ActiveSupport::StringInquirer`, which overrides `method_missing` in order to provide that nice equality syntax. Check: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/StringInquirer.html

So, if you want to override it to be "production" by defaut, you should write:

```
Rails.env ||= ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new('production')
```

However, you'll have to check which is the uninitialized value of `Rails.env`, I'm not sure it's really `nil`.

The best course of action, IMO, is to just prepend `env RAILS_ENV=production` to all your scripts.

Comment: Ah - now this is useful, So "env(RAILS_ENV)" is how you manually set and environment variable now?

Comment: *g* just looked into the source-code for Rails.env - now added to the question...

Answer (score 9):

Edit `lib/tasks/environments.rake`

```
# Sets environments as needed for rake tasks
%w[development production staging].each do |env|
  desc "Runs the following task in the #{env} environment" 
  task env do
    Rails.env = env
  end
end

task :testing do
  Rake::Task["test"].invoke
end

task :dev do
  Rake::Task["development"].invoke
end

task :prod do
  Rake::Task["production"].invoke
end
```

[Source](http://lindsaar.net/2010/5/18/Upgrading_RailsPlugins_org_to_Rails_3_Part_1)

**UPDATE**

[pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690121/rails-3-creating-a-production-database) `RAILS_ENV=production` via command line, something like this:

`RAILS_ENV=production rake db:setup`

Does [this](http://gregmoreno.ca/rails-3-upgrade-part-3-code-fixes-views-and-forms/) help:

```
# before
if RAILS_ENV == 'production'
  ...

# Rails 3
if Rails.env.production?
```

Comment: ok, scuse my ignorance but: 1) how would you then invoke tasks and 2) how would this affect daemons (which in our case are not invoked via rake).

Comment: Oh... and just o be through: 3) how does this solution match our requirement to "default to production if nothing is passed on the command-line, but otherwise allow us to override it if we do pass something on the command line" ?

Comment: Hiya - yes, this explains how to use rake tasks... but what about our daemons?

Comment: Ok, looking deeper into the posts from which you've taken this code - I have to say it probably isn't appropriate for me at all. The environment.rake code you've borrowed - is from somebody's custom rake environments. It *only* covers setting the environment for rake tasks.

Comment: The second bit of code you've provided - comes directly from the docs which I have already used. As I specified - I have already updated our code to use Rails.env instead of RAILS_ENV in all our usual code.

Comment: The questions that remain outstanding are the main ones I ask in this post: Our daemons are initiated by cron - not rake, so rake is not relevant to this case. So: can you use Rails.env in a daemon? if so, can you pass RAILS_ENV on the command-line and have it set Rails.env? if so - how?

Comment: by daemons you mean cron jobs? Does this help: http://wiki.joyent.com/smartmachine%3arails%3acron ?

Answer (score 2):

```
if Rails.env.production?
  puts '...'
```

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstand the requirements. I don't want to know whether or not I am in the production environment. I want to force my scripts to run in the production environment by default.