# rspec test using regular database not test database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I am using Rspec, webrat, selenium rc for tests.

I am trying to do integration test with selenium and rspec.

I just looked in my development database and learned that my integration tests are using my development database and not my test database.

How an I configure rails and rspec and selenium to use my test database.

All my other tests seem to be using my test database.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you have a line like

```
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
```

in your spec_helper.rb?
does it force the use of the test db if you add/replace it with

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'
```

And could this be the root of your problem from yesterday - re email validation??

Comment: Hey Chrispanda I changed my code to match yours above. This did not change the writing to the development database but I think that is how selenium works if I am running it from my system. It can't write to the test database as the tests are going through firefox. But I fixed the uniqueness problem by wiping out my database. This was the problem, I thought it was writing to my test db so I would do rake db:test:prepare and not rake db:reset.  Ughhhh. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how I can wipe out my development db after each test?

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser - it's possible that a rails app uses an external data source populated by another app and the rails app is only an interface to that data. It's not always appropriate to use a test databse.

Comment: David: If it is appropriate to use a database in the first place, then it is always appropriate to have a test database. If the Rails app is only using an external data source, then it probably doesn't need a DB in the first place (and so different testing strategies will apply).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue (rspec tests running against development rather than test environment) while porting and Rails 2 app to Rails 3.  Changing the line

```
ENV["Rails.env"] ||= 'test'
```

to

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
```

in spec_helper.rb fixed my issue.

I realize that RAILS_ENV has been deprecated in favor of Rails.env and suspect that something bad has been dragged over in the port forcing me to make this change.

There is also a good discussion of RAILS_ENV and Rails.env here which may provide some more insight:

[Correct Ruby on Rails 3 replacement for ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'production'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017069/correct-rails-3-replacement-for-envrails-env-production)

Answer (score 0):

According to rspec-rails gem docs, put rspec-rails gem in the development and test groups of the Gemfile. This is because the test rake task loads development environment first before switching to test environment.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

References: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7175 , https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8591 -- rspec loads development environment