# Separate Sinatra app's test database from development database?

Tags: rspec, sinatra, datamapper

As a learning exercise, I am building a practice app using Sinatra, Datamapper and RSpec. I am using [this template](https://github.com/ausgat/sinatra-datamapper-template), which is basically a boilerplate for all the above.

The problem I am having is that the way RSpec and Datamapper seem to be configured, every time a spec is run that tests Database related functionality, those tests directly change my development database instead of a test database.

For example, I wish to create a few database objects before running the rest of the spec...

```
before(:all) {
  Region.new(:country => "Canada", :country_code => "CA").save
  ProductLine.new(:reference => "Molders").save
  Product.new(:name => "The Black Molder").save
  Cart.new(:price => 25.95).save
}
```

Yet every time I run RSpec, the above elements get added to my development database.

**Why isn't a test database being generated instead?** How can I get the test database to work properly?

This appears pretty similar to [this issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595682/rspec-test-using-regular-database-not-test-database), except for Sinatra instead of Rails.

If it's any help, my code can be seen [here](https://bitbucket.org/jeffkamo/fusic-molder/src).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In `spec_helper.rb` file you are requiring `my_app.rb` file which in turn requires `db.rb` to set up your database, but this happens *before* you call `set :environment, :test`, so the `configure :test` block isn't being run (the environment is the default development at that stage).

Of course you can't call `set environment :test` before you require Sinatra, but you can set the `RACK_ENV` environment variable, which Sinatra checks when setting its environment.

So to make sure you're running in the test environment, add this to the top of `spec_helper.rb` (or somewhere else at the start of your tests, but before you require Sinatra):

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'
```

You could then remove the `set :environment, :test` line as it's now redundant.

This is similar to the other question you reference, but rack apps use `RACK_ENV` instead of `RAILS_ENV`.

Comment: Thanks, I was putting `ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'` in various places and getting frustrated as to why it wasn't picking it up - after reading your answer I put it at the top of `spec_helper.rb` **before** `require 'sinatra'` and now it works!