# Rails confused between dev and test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm just moving my rails app to a new development machine.
for the first time, I am running rails on ubuntu in a virtualbox on a windows 7 host OS.

When I run rake db:create, it creates the rails_app_test.

When I run rails s, I get the error

```
unknown database rails_app_dev
```

I am trying to use the development environment, but for some reason rake is creating test. Why is this, and how do i correct it?

Comment: Your question is essentially answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690121/rails-3-creating-a-production-database

Answer (score 2):

Your environment variable seems to equal 'test'.

Try:

```
 rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```