# How to copy data in development db to product db using sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

I am using sqlite for both (for now) my development and production system  on rails. I have a development.sqlite3 file that I want to copy over to production.sqlite3 to run some testing in a production environment.

I've tried to copy the development db over to the production just by doing `mv development.sqlite3 production.sqlite3` and that doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas on how best to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3690128/524293) the following code does it.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create db:schema:load
```

**This empties out the current production.sqlite3**. After the database creation and loading of the structure you can copy the development.sqlite3 to production.sqlite3 to copy your data.

```
cp db/development.sqlite3 db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't seem to be working. Is there a way to test to make sure the data is in production.sqlite3 and a way to make sure that rails knows it is in the production environment.

Comment: I just ran `select * from posts;` inside of sqlite3 and confirmed there is no data in the db. Am I doing something wrong? I ran those commands from the command line and it seemed to work with output that you would expect.

Comment: To start rails server in production you run `rails server production`, and to start the console you run `rails console -e production`. You found no data in production.sqlite3 with sqlite3? If you've copied development.sqlite3 you should have the exact same data, no matter what Rails can see.

Comment: Did you copy the file again after db:create and db:schema:load? Otherwise it actually should be empty, as db:schema:load clears out the current db.

Comment: yeah, I forgot to copy it over after I ran that.