# Nitrous.io cannot start rails in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, production, puma

I'm using a free Nitrous.IO box and the app runs fine in development mode but this is what i am getting in production mode:

```
       => Booting Puma                                                                                                                                                                       
    => Rails 4.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000                                                                                                              
    => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options                                                                                                                                     
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server                                                                                                                                                          
    Puma 2.8.1 starting...                                                                                                                                                                
    * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16                                                                                                                                                     
    * Environment: production                                                                                                                                                             
    * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000                                                                                                                                                     
    I, [2014-03-31T01:21:24.636846 #25073]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 50.9.170.255 at         2014-03-31 01:21:24 +0000                                                                       
    I, [2014-03-31T01:21:24.666459 #25073]  INFO -- : Processing by PostsController#index as   HTML                                                                                         
    E, [2014-03-31T01:21:24.690904 #25073] ERROR -- : PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation    "users" does not exist                                                                         
    LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 2  ORDE...                                                                                                               
                               ^                                                                                                                                                      
    : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1                                                                                           
    I, [2014-03-31T01:21:24.692268 #25073]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in   25ms                                                                                         
    F, [2014-03-31T01:21:24.695776 #25073] FATAL -- :                                                                                                                                     
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist                                                                                           
    LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 2  ORDE...                                                                                                               
                               ^                                                                                                                                                      
    : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1):                                                                                         
     activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in      `async_exec'                                                                                
     activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_no_cache'                                                                             
  activerecord (4.0.0)   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:138:in `block in   exec_query'                                                           
      activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in   `block in log'                                                                                
     activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'                                                                                           
    activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in  `log'                                                                                         
    activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'                                                                    
     activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:885:in `select'                                                                                    
     activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:24:in `select_all'                                                                       
     activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:61:in `block in select_all'                                                                      
     activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:76:in `cache_sql'                                                                                
     activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:61:in `select_all'                                                                               
     activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/querying.rb:36:in `find_by_sql'                                                                                                              
     activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/relation.rb:585:in `exec_queries'                                                                                                            
     activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/relation.rb:471:in `load'                                                                                                                    
      activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/relation.rb:220:in `to_a'                                                                                                                    
     activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:325:in `find_first'                                                                                               
     activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:90:in `first'                                                                                                     
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb:129:in `first'                                                                             
     orm_adapter (0.5.0) lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb:17:in `get'                                                                                                           
     devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:208:in `serialize_from_session'                                                                                                 
     devise (3.2.4) lib/devise.rb:462:in `block (2 levels) in configure_warden!'                                                                                                         
     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/session_serializer.rb:34:in `fetch' 
     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:212:in `user'                                                                                                                                    
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:318:in `_perform_authentication'                                                                                                                 
     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:127:in `authenticate!'                                                                                                                           
     devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:50:in `authenticate_user!'                                                                                                         
     activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:417:in `_run__2080870772581885230__process_action__callbacks'                                                                 
     activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'                                                                                                         
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'                                                                                                      
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'                                                                                                     
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'                                                                                   
     activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'                                                                                              
     activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'                                                                                           
     activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'                                                                                                       
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'                                                                                            
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'                                                                                            
     activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'                                                                                        
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'                                                                                                                 
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'                                                                                                             
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'                                                                                                                 
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'                                                                                                  
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'                                                                                                          
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'                                                                                                            
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'                                                                                                        
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'                                                                                                            
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'                                                                                                      
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'                                                                                                               
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'                                                                                                               
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'                                                                                                           
     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'                                                                                                                          
     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'                                                                                                                                  
     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'                                                                                                                                   
     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'                                                                                                                                          
     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'                                                                                                                                
     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'                                                                                                                                          
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'                                                                                                     
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'                                                                                                            
     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'                                                                                                                       
     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'                                                                                                                          
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'                                                                                                          
     activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'                                                                                                                  
     activerecord (4.0.0)   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'                                                                                                
     activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2769160116473194702__call__callbacks'                                                                           
     activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'                                                                                                         
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'                                                                                                         
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'                                                                                                         
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'                                                                                                  
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'                                                                                                   
     railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'                                                                                                                          
     railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'                                                                                                                     
     activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'                                                                                                  
     activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'                                                                                                           
     activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'                                                                                                           
     railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'                                                                                                                              
     actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'                                                                                                        
     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'                                                                                                                                
     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'                                                                                                                                       
     activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'                                                                                                 
     railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'                                                                                                                                  
     railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'                                                                                                                              
     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'                                                                                                                                
     puma (2.8.1) lib/puma/server.rb:490:in `handle_request'                                                                                                                             
     puma (2.8.1) lib/puma/server.rb:361:in `process_client'                                                                                                                             
     puma (2.8.1) lib/puma/server.rb:254:in `block in run'                                                                                                                               
     puma (2.8.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `call'                                                                                                                                   
     puma (2.8.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

**UPDATE:**

I managed to create the productoction database by running the db:create and I can start in production mode but none of my css is loading so it was recommened I run the command below but get rake aborted!
After running

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get this

```
   rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                                         
   Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "  background:": expected pseudoclass or   pseudoelement, was "/* homepage */"                                                                     
  (in /home/action/booklist/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)                                                                                                                   
(sass):1186                                                                                                                                                                           
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1147:in     `expected'                                                                                    
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1085:in   `expected'                                                                                    
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1067:in  `expr!'                                                                                       
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:794:in `pseudo'                                                                                       
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:678:in `simple_selector_sequence'                                                                     
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:640:in `_selector'                                                                                    
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:619:in `selector'                                                                                     
    /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:603:in `selector_sequence'                                                                            
    /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:528:in `ruleset'                                                                                      
    /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:553:in `block_child'                                                                                  
    /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:546:in `block_contents'                                                                               
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:82:in `stylesheet'                                                                                    
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:27:in `parse'                                                                                         
  /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/engine.rb:342:in `_to_tree'                                                                                          
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'                                                                                           
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'                                                                                            
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:24:in `evaluate'                                                                        
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'                                                                                           
  /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-   2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'                                                                      
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'                                                                                   
   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'                                                                               
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'                                                                        
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'                                                                                       
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'                                                                               
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'                                                                      
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'                                                                             
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'                                                                               
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'                                                                                
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'                                                                                
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'                                                                   
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'                                                                             
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'                                                                            
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'                                                                      
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'                                                                                  
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'                                                                               
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'                                                      
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'                                                                           
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'                                                      
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'                                                                                                           
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'                                                                                                         
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: Are you certain that the `users` table exists in your related database? (`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist`)

Comment: I'm certain because I created a few accounts in dev mode and was able to login, logout, create posts etc..

Comment: Did you run your migrations in production ,`bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` ?

Comment: What about your production database?

Comment: ok i created the database with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3690128/1230075  it runs in production mode now but my CSS isn't loading, the page has no css

Comment: do a `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: ok the command worked but still no css in page